# How to run list of Futures concurrently?

Tags: kotlin, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use the AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsync.sendEmailAsync to send batches of emails concurrently, but for some reason I'm really struggling to find the correct way to do it.

While looping through my list of recipients, I'm creating futures like so...

```
val recipientEmailAddress = it.emailAddress

val result: Future<SendEmailResult> = client.sendEmailAsync(SendEmailRequest()
                                            .withMessage(message)
                                            .withDestination(Destination()
                                                    .withToAddresses(recipientEmailAddress))
                                            .withSource("sender@mydomain.com")
                                    , object: com.amazonaws.handlers.AsyncHandler<SendEmailRequest,SendEmailResult> {
                                        override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                                            LOG.error("Error sending email.", e)
                                            failedList.add(it)
                                        }

                                        override fun onSuccess(request: SendEmailRequest, result: SendEmailResult?) {
                                            LOG.debug("Successfully sent email $recipientEmailAddress")
                                            successList.add(it)
                                        }
                                    });

futureList.add(result);
```

I can then get these to run by doing the following...

```
val resultList = futureList.map { it.get() }
```

The problem is that this doesn't run the calls concurrently, each call to it.get() blocks until it has a result, meaning they're all running sequentially, negating the benefit of using sendEmailAsync.

What is the correct way to do this?

I simply want to do the following:

1. Call sendEmailAsync for each recipient
2. Run all calls concurrently
3. Wait for all to complete

I don't think I need (or want) to use multiple threads. I don't need parallel processing, I just want the calls to Amazon SES to happen concurrently.

This is trivial in C# etc. but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with Kotlin/Java.

Comment: This implementation should already be sending all the emails concurrently.  Yes, each `.get()` will block waiting for one particular email, but *all* the emails should be in flight.  This implementation is fine if you don't mind your thread blocking until the emails are done.  If you're doing this in a suspend function and you need it to suspend, though, you'll have to make changes to arrange that.

Comment: Thanks @MattTimmermans After further investigation, it seems it was my database update code, which was confusing me, as it was sequentially updating all the records to indicate success or failure. I can see now that the actual email delivery is running concurrently.